# Best way to share a JSON file via nuget?

Tags: json, nuget

I have a JSON schema describing how to communicate with a .NET microservice I am developing. I would like to share this JSON schema (along with various other poco objects) in a nuget file with other services who wish to communicate with me over Kafka.

My question is, how can I share this file using nuget? It's trivial to share the poco objects, but I'm not sure how to share something like a static JSON file, and am also unsure how the consumer of this nuget package would then reference and consume that JSON file.

I've tried searching the nuget documentation but couldn't find anything. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the docs on content files in nupkgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files), but note that this is the reference for the `.nuspec` file. If you're packing a project file this is typically automatically generated for you.

There are two ways for a project to use NuGet packages, either with `packages.config` or `PackageReference` (SDK projects, used by .NET Core, only support `PackageReference`). When installing a package for a `packages.config` project, NuGet will look at all the files under the `content` directory within the `nupkg` and copy them to the project's folder. On the other hand, projects that use `PackageReference` will not copy the files, instead MSBuild Content items are creates for files in the `contentFiles` directory of the package in the global packages folder. Therefore, if you want to support users of your package whether they use `packages.config` or `PackageReference`, you need to duplicate content files in both the `content` and `contentFiles` directories in the `nupkg`. If you pack a SDK style project, the pack targets will automatically add any content items to both the `content` and `contentFiles` directories in the `nupkg`.

So, you need to consider how users of your package will use the json file (both whether they will be using `packages.config` or `PackageReference`, and what they will do with the file once it's on their computer). If it's something that they'll only use programatically, it might be easier for you to just embed the json file in your assembly as an embedded resource, and provide them a method to call to get the file as a string. That way the difference between `packages.config` and `PackageReference` is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I would be supporting PackageReference only, but I think I prefer your second suggestion about having the file as an embedded resource.

Comment: You can actually create a Nuget package that can be consumed by both types of the projects.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63299701/761755

Comment: @zivkan, with the approach you proposed, how do you inform the developer about the structure of the response?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following peice of code in your .csproj file of your application/library.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="xxx\myconfig.json" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles\any\any;content">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

This will add myconfig.json where the NuGet is been installed.

Comment: Note: Pack this from visual studio